# Webcam not found (no img stream) cv2.error: ... (-215) size.width>0 &&

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I know, there is several threads already on this topic, my situation seems not to be solved yet though. I just can't make my programs take images with my webcam (B910 by Logitech) on a laptop.
I am running a program on a Ubuntu 16.04, that is working on other machines with the same webcam I am using. For the sake of easiness, here a minimum version:

```
import cv2
device = -1
def show_webcam(mirror=False):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
    print cam.isOpened(), cam.read()
    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        if mirror:
            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The print command yields: False, (False, None)
Running cheese from command line, shows webcam stream as it should, also the build in camera is working.
So I tried -1, 0, 1, 2 and other values for device and nothing works. I put a time.sleep(2) after cam =..., also without result. I don't find much more on this, can anyone help? Thanks!

Note: 
`cv2.__file__` is 'usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.so'

`cv2.__version__` is '3.2.0'

`cv2.getBuildInformation()` is a little long for here, might there be some important information?

Comment: Why device = -1 ? normally should be 0 if you've one single camera, 1 or 2 ..otherwise

Comment: The -1 assigns the first device it finds. I had tried out 0,1,2 also, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete devices and change the code to `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, and see if it works?
Normally if your camera is working with cheese, the driver programme should be okay.

The `cv2.videocapture(0)` is for the device default.
Do you have another camera device with your computer in the moment?

Comment: I tried, it does not, Should be the same anyways, as I had tired it out ith device = 0. I have the built-in camera of the laptop and one of two B910 that I am planning to use. All combinations fail. That cheese is working and this here is not really is a weird thing to me.

Comment: @mamamamama:  emm, i can't say what's the real reason for that. Can just give you an advice is to set the resolution of it. If your computer is with usb2.0, maybe there will be a probleme of bandwide.

Comment: Mmmmm it works on other computers with 2.0 switches, too. I think it might be something different.